# Material UI disable checkbox hover

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to disable round hover around Material UI Checkbox component. When Checkbox is not checked hover is disabled but I need to disable hover also when Checkbox is checked. Any tips how to do that?

Here is my Checkbox component:

```
<FormControlLabel
    control={
        <Checkbox
             className={classes.checkbox}
             icon={
                 <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon />
             }
             checkedIcon={
                 <CheckBoxIcon />
             }
        />
/>
```

And here is my styling. This removes hover when Checkbox is not checked but not when Checkbox is checked:

```
checkbox: {
    "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
    },
},
```

Comment: means you totally want to remove hover from checkbox, right?

Comment: Yes. I didn't found any prop from documentation and styling removes hover only when it's not checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the hover effect comes from the `IconButton` component which is nested inside the checkbox. to disable this target the root class and add the background color with `!important` so as the hover effect of `IconButton` has a higher specificity.

```
<FormControlLabel
  control={
    <Checkbox
      disableRipple
      icon={<CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize="small" />}
      checkedIcon={<CheckBoxIcon fontSize="small" />}
      classes={{root:classes.root}}
    />
  }
  label="Custom size"
/>
```

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent !important'
    }
  }
}));
```

Here is the working demo :-
[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Comment: no need to bring out the big guns, `'&&:hover'` is all the specificity you need

Comment: This one works! Also found out you don't have to target root element, only !important is enough to fix my problem.

Comment: @hotpink This solution works also and actuallu I ended up to use it. Thanks!

Comment: @Arttu `className` always targets `root`, you only need `classes` when targeting nested elements or pseudo selectors

Comment: @hotpink I didn't know about `&&:hover`. thanks for it. Can you please its documentation link that can explain it's working in brief?

Comment: ampersand always refers to the parent selector, so instead of `.makeStyles-root-1:hover` you end up with `.makeStyles-root-1.makeStyles-root-1:hover` , which has a higher specificity. Not sure where this is explicitly documented

Answer (score 1):

well, to remove hover from checkbox, I would like to suggest that you have to create css file let's called it

> global.css file

after that put some classes in out case :

```
.MuiCheckbox-root > span::before {
  background: none !important;
  transform: none !important;
}
```

why I said because sometimes it's a bit hard to override style from

> createMUitheme function

I hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can style component with classes prop:

```
checkbox: {
    "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
    }
},
checkedbox: {
   backgroundColor: "transparent",
}


<FormControlLabel
    control={
        <Checkbox
             classes={{ root: classes.checkbox, checked: classes.checkedbox}}
             icon={
                 <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon />
             }
             checkedIcon={
                 <CheckBoxIcon />
             }
        />
/>
```

Document here:

https://material-ui.com/api/checkbox/

https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes

Comment: It's not working. Also tried to nest hover inside "&:checked" but it's not working either.

Comment: you need to use classes props with `checked` rule name, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

2023 update - they've added a `disableRipple` prop to the Checkbox component to turn off the hover state entirely without CSS. Just use:

```
<Checkbox disableRipple={true} />
```

Answer (score 0):

No one mentioned pointer event being set to none. Given, I did came to this question with chakra UI not material UI, but it seems Material UI also has pointer event.

My solution in Chakra UI:

```
  <Checkbox size="lg" pointerEvents={"none"} />
```

I tried following the class approach mentioned in the solutions here using tailwind
 `className="!bg-transparent !hover:bg-transparent"` but that didn't work for me.